# Weird outline when clicking contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, css, contenteditable

I'm trying to create a textarea that can contain multiple colors.  I created a div and in JS did the following:

```
element.unselectable = 'off';
element.contentEditable = true;
```

The div is now editable, but when I click in it, it gets a weird outline.  How do I turn this off?
[alt text http://www.benmccann.com/test/contentEditable.png](http://www.benmccann.com/test/contentEditable.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set the outline-property in your CSS to "none":

```
<style type="text/css">
    * { outline: none; }
</style>
```

Comment: What if you don't want to remove the outline on all element, just the affected div?

Comment: Ah, just change the selector to that div. Easy.